# Is there a way to get my old passwords from the Have I Been Pwned website?

Tags: passwords, password-recovery

I have an old device I am trying to get access to but I have forgotten my password.

I would like to try my pwned passwords that are in the [Have I Been Pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) database.

Is there a way to get my old passwords from this site?

Comment: You do realise that would be the equivalent of re-posting everybody's hacked passwords right there in public??

Comment: They could send the password to the email address that it was paired with

Answer (score 0):

No. HIPB does not provide any plaintext passwords, for obvious security reasons.

They only store the hash of a password, for purposes of seeing if a password you give them has been used.

And before you ask, you can't decrypt the passwords. They're all SHA-1 and NTLM, which, as far as I'm aware, are both practically non-reversible hashes.

What this means is, you could try a few guesses as to what the password is. If you get a matching hash to something in the database, you found the password. If you don't, then you didn't- either you got the wrong password, or they don't have the right password.

Note though, this would take a long time. These hash files are several gigabytes in size. One test would take just a while, but testing a dozen or more passwords which you might have, that would take hours, maybe days.